# Python 2.7: Remove part of element in SET

Tags: python, python-2.7

The given set is:

```
seta = (['3;\t103;\tB03;\t01-06-2018;\t10:23:20;\t07:15:10\n',
         '10;\t110;\tB10;\t01-06-2018;\t10:30:00;\t07:40:10\n'])
```

Need to remove `\t`, expected `set` should look like:

```
['3,103,B03,01-06-2018,10:23:20,07:15:10\n',
 '10,110,B10,01-06-2018,10:30:00,07:40:10\n']
```

Comment: It is a list of two strings, not a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
seta = (['3;\t103;\tB03;\t01-06-2018;\t10:23:20;\t07:15:10\n', '10;\t110;\tB10;\t01-06-2018;\t10:30:00;\t07:40:10\n'])
print([x.replace(';\t', ',') for x in seta])

# ['3,103,B03,01-06-2018,10:23:20,07:15:10\n', '10,110,B10,01-06-2018,10:30:00,07:40:10\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use simple python one-liner

```
    seta = [string.replace(";\t", ", ") for string in seta]
```

Hope it helped!